# How to make div/container change background color when child element has focus?

Tags: html, css, focus

I have the following html:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>some text here</p>
    <input type='text' />
</div>
```

...with the following CSS:

```
.mydiv {
    background-color:yellow;
}

.mydiv:focus, .mydiv:hover {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

The `:hover` is changing the background color appropriately, but the `:focus` is not having any effect. Is this because the `<div>` cannot truly have focus?

Is there a CSS solution to make `.mydiv` change background color when any of its children receive focus?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhmCg/13/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no CSS solution for this. But, you can achieve this by using jQuery.

```
$(".mydiv").children().focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "orange");
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvfy9pzn/7/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `tabindex` attribute to the element needs to be focusable.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhmCg/14/)

But, to answer your question, there is no pure CSS solution to make the div bg color change if its children receive focus.

Comment: My question was how to make the div bg color change when any of its *children* have focus.

Comment: Then there isn't a pure CSS solution

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery, I think you're better off using the `focusin` and `focusout` events.

The code as adapted from the accepted answer would then become:

```
$(".mydiv").focusin(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
}).focusout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

though, personally, I'd rather use a "focus" class:

```
$(".mydiv").focusin(function() {
    $(this).addClass("focus");
}).focusout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("focus");
});
```

combined with the css for the combined selector:

```
.mydiv.focus { background-color: orange }
```

p.s. For once, I find [the bit of docs on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusin.asp) more informative than [the demo on api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/), which just looks confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Possible CSS solution:

```
<style>
    #row1 {display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;  z-index: 150;}
    .BGmagic {display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #efefef; z-index: 200;}
    #inputone{display: block; position: relative; z-index: 250;}
    #inputone:focus + .BGmagic {display: block;}
    #inputone:hover + .BGmagic {display: block;}
</style>

<form>
    <div ID="row1">
        <p style="position: relative; z-index: 250;">First name:</p>
        <input ID="inputone" type="text" name="firstname">
        <div class="BGmagic"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```